# recommendation for the best 3d mapping tool?

Tags: 3d, camera, kinect, realsense, primesense

I need to map a face to a high quality 3d model so what is the best between kinect ,realsense ,etc ?and what is the hardware requirements to use it?

Answer (score 0):

The camera that you have to choose depends on how far is the face from the camera. **All different cameras work well in different distance ranges.**

***for example:*** in Kinect an object has to be minimum 0.5m (meters) away to detect depth of any object. Thus kinect v2 could be useful if the range is between 0.5m to 5m (though the range is higher for this device)

***For short range:***

- Intel Realsense SR300 (range 0.2m to 1.2m). Provide SDK where they have methods for detecting faces.
- Intel realsense R200 (range 0.7m to 3m). Could be used as well.

Both the devices provide support in different languages and APIs are there using which the 3D point cloud could be created.

This area is in active research and new and better cameras are coming out.

Answer (score 0):

For long range:
Intel RealSense D400 series can be used.

And, RealSense SDK 2.0 which is on the GitHub supports the cross-platform development for D400 series and SR300.